# Check multiple empty clauses

Tags: php

I am currently having a bit of a refactoring issue, I am refactoring a function which checks if a number of class properties are null or undefined. The function currently does this in the following manner namely:

```
 return (
            empty($postcodeRow->getAddress())
            && empty($postcodeRow->getCity())
            && empty($postcodeRow->getSurcharge())
        );
```

I was wondering as I know you can chain isset's but is there a way to chain multiple empty clauses in PHP?

Comment: What is the problem with NOT chaining?

Comment: It works however I was just wondering if there was another method in this instance (and I have tried to think of them) because it isn't the nicest looking.

Comment: Your code is valid in PHP 5.5+, saying isn't the nicest looking thing is very subjective. If you want to make it "prettier" you can make your own function which takes a variable number of arguments and checks if any of them is empty and returns the result.